# mysql to mssql grouping with mixed fields

Tags: mysql, sql-server, group-by

I want to execute a simple query on a ms-sql server which is working fine in mysql but seems impossible on the microsoft stuff.

Works fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(event_date) AS Amount, event_date, DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%y-%m-%d') AS Timestep 
FROM JRLOG 
GROUP BY Timestep;
```

Works only when I remove the event_date field from the query

```
SELECT COUNT(event_date) AS Amount, event_date, FORMAT(event_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS Timestep 
FROM [JRLOG] 
GROUP BY FORMAT(event_date,'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

And why can´t I use the virtual Timestep field in the GROUP part at MSSQL?

I get the MSSQL error:

> event_date column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in an aggregate function and not in the GROUP BY clause

Is there a possibillity to take the event_date or another field with me in the SELECT query?

Comment: Did you miss something here `..., event_date FORMAT(e...`

Comment: Also, on a different note, I strongly recommend avoiding `FORMAT`if you're using SQL Server, it's an awfully slow function. ***IF*** you do need to control the format of a value in your data use `CONVERT` to change the datatype to a `varchar`, and use a style code: [Date and time styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles).

Comment: The error, which those familiar with SQL Server won't need to translate  (as MySQL doesn't care for a proper `GROUP BY` clause so wouldn't generate an error), is telling you the problem. `event_date` is not contained in an aggregated function and is not in the `GROUP BY`. it needs to be one or the other.

Comment: The missing "," between event_date and FORMAT in the ms-query was only a misstype here, sorry. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you mean:

```
SELECT COUNT(event_date) AS Amount, event_date, FORMAT(event_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS Timestep 
FROM [JRLOG] 
GROUP BY event_date,FORMAT(event_date,'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(event_date) AS Amount, MIN(event_date), FORMAT(event_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS Timestep 
FROM [JRLOG] 
GROUP BY FORMAT(event_date,'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: MIN(event_date) The second one. That was the solution which as it seems Mysql made automatically. Thanks

Comment: as i recall mysql will take the first entry in the table for an ungrouped field. if the table is ordered by eventdate that will be the MIN. otherwise, it may not be.